# All dynamic libraries on Z/os

Tags: zos

I would like to see all libraries which are accessible during dynamic linking (like `ldconfig -p`) but on IBM Z/os.

[Here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.2.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r2.bpxa500/shcmddes.htm) is list of shell commands but it does not have `ldconfig` or anything related.

Comment: Verifying, are you asking with regards to UNIX System Services?

Comment: @zarchasmpgmr yes

Comment: Dynamic linking is a little different on z/OS since the target library can be pretty much anywhere, including conventional z/OS datasets, LPA, LNKLST and so forth. When a dynamically linked function is encountered at execution time, I believe IBM's code can either search the directories in the LIBPATH environment variable, or do a conventional z/OS load, depending on the name of the DLL. This is very flexible, but it means that it's hard to know in advance where a DLL will actually come from. What problem are you trying to solve that you need this information?

Comment: thank you for your reply @ValerieR, I wanted to know if there is a standard C library, so I could dynamically load it. Thus I thought to find first how this C library is called.

Comment: Most of the common runtime functions are provided in z/OS by a component called "LE" (Language Environment)...a common runtime library shared across all the mainframe compilers, from C/C++ to COBOL and PL/I. It's generally integrated into the operating system in that the common functions are in a few datasets, typically named CEE.SCEERUN and so on...usually you don't have to worry about the base LE libraries - the functions that initialize your C/C++ program are in them, so if they aren't setup properly, your app won't even start (and thus dynamically loading them isn't really possible).

Comment: Application DLLs work differently...when you reference your own DLL, an IMPORT file ("side deck") tells the runtime where the function lives: "symbol X is in library A". On first reference, the runtime searches for module A, opens it, and resolves the symbol. z/OS being complex, the search for A is also complicated...it can be a UNIX-path found via LIBPATH, or it can be a z/OS dataset found by searching STEPLIB and the normal system libraries...if the name is ambiguous, both searches are performed.

Comment: IBM explains z/OS's DLL search and load behaviors that Valerie R summarized in more detail here (z/OS 2.4-based reference link, subject to change):

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.4.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r4.ceea200/loaddll.htm